# Google Apps Script getWidth() for document table cell width returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, grid-layout

I'd like to insert image in the Google document by using Google Apps Script, and to spread it (the image) to the width of the page - margins or to insert it in the table cell and spread it to the width of the cell.

The code goes like this:

```
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
var insertPlace = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
insertPlace.asText().setText("");
var insertedImage = insertPlace.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, image);
var h = insertedImage.getHeight();
var w = insertedImage.getWidth();
insertedImage.setWidth(width).setHeight(width * h / w);
```

And where is the problem?

width!

How to find width of the table cell or body?

I have tried with

```
var width = insertPlace.getParent().asParagraph().asTableCell().getWidth();
```

but got null although cell is in the single column of the table, and table takes all the width of the page-margins.

Anyone got the idea about how to get width of the cell?

Also, how to get page width, margins etc...

UPDATE

I have discovered that the issue must be with the Google code about this.
Actually, they have made differently handling with tables in slides compared to document:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell

In slides version there is, for example, getParentColumn(), which is not available for the document... any many similar discrepancies.

What are doing these guys at Google?!?!?

Comment: Your first link is from slides and the second is from documents, which are different methods so there is no reason getParent() should be in both of them.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420215/

Answer (score 2):

This is not perfect but it seems to get me pretty close.  May be you could work with it some more and get the rest of the way.  I thought that the PAGE_WIDTH and PAGE_HEIGHT were in points but when I look at the number it seemed rather large so I used them as pixels instead.  And it appears to work for me the image is centered in the page and goes from left margin to right margin.  I didn't adjust the page height because my image looked ok but you might wish to do that.

```
function insertImage() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var atts=body.getAttributes();
  for(var att in atts) {
    Logger.log(att + ':' + atts[att]);
  }
  var folderId="Folder ID";
  var files=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    if(file.getName()=="Image File Name") {
      var image=file.getBlob().getAs('image/png');//may need to change content type
      var img=body.appendImage(image);
      var h=img.getHeight();
      var w=img.getWidth();
      var mr=atts['MARGIN_RIGHT'];
      var ml=atts['MARGIN_LEFT'];
      var sw=atts['PAGE_WIDTH'];
      var sh=atts['PAGE_HEIGHT'];
      img.setHeight(sw*h/w);
      img.setWidth((sh-mr-ml)*w/h);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper for the answer and it helped me to search in the right direction! Actually, getAttributes() retrieves MARGIN_LEFT, MARGIN_RIGHT, PAGE_WIDTH and PAGE_HEIGHT, but I couldn't manage to get it to work for TABLE_CELL, because it returns null for it's width. That null must be a bug, so I reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143810853

Comment: By the way, why do you use w/h next to sh-mr-ml for the width of the image?

Comment: And, there is another issue here. sh-mr-ml gives correct margin-to-margin width but I had to multiply width of the inserted image by correction factor of exactly 4/3 to had the image from coast to coast. Why this 4/3?

Comment: I don’t know I’ve never done this before as I said it’s not a perfect solution. I just thought it was something you could work with and take it to a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of getWidth so that we can compute new good width value for newly inserted image.

```js
function getWidthOf(element, pageWidth) {
  if (!element) {
    return 0;
  }
  const type = element.getType() + "";
  const parent = element.getParent();
  if (false) { }
  else if (type === "TABLE_CELL") {
    const atts = element.getAttributes();
    let width = element.asTableCell().getWidth();
    if (width === null) {
      width = getWidthOf(parent, pageWidth);
    }
    return width - (atts["PADDING_LEFT"] || 0) - (atts["PADDING_RIGHT"] || 0);
  }
  else if (type === "TABLE_ROW") {
    const cx = element.asTableRow().getNumCells();
    return getWidthOf(parent, pageWidth) / cx;
  }
  else if (type === "TABLE") {
    const atts = element.getAttributes();
    return getWidthOf(parent, pageWidth) - (atts["BORDER_WIDTH"] || 0);
  }
  else if (type === "BODY_SECTION") {
    const atts = element.getAttributes();
    return pageWidth - atts["MARGIN_LEFT"] - atts["MARGIN_RIGHT"];
  }
  else {
    return getWidthOf(parent, pageWidth);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
function insertImageTest() {
  const templateDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID/edit");
  const templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDoc.getId());
  const document = DocumentApp.openById(templateFile.getId());
  const body = document.getBody();
  const found = body.findText("HERE!");
  if (!found) {
    throw new Error("No insert point found!");
  }

  const imageBlob = DriveApp.getFileById("YOUR_IMAGE_FILE_ID_IN_DRIVE").getBlob();

  const paragraph = found.getElement().getParent().asParagraph();
  paragraph.clear();
  const img = paragraph.appendInlineImage(imageBlob);
  const newWidth = getWidthOf(paragraph, body.getAttributes()["PAGE_WIDTH"]) * 1.33;
  const newHeight = img.getHeight() * newWidth / img.getWidth();
  img.setWidth(newWidth).setHeight(newHeight);
}
```

*Notes*:

- Paper metric unit is **pt**. However Image's setWidth and setHeight work in **pixel** unit.
- This conversion (`pixels = pt * 1.33`) works but I don't know whether this is right or not.